# Decimal place in element id for jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

The html code is

```
<div class="content" id="content-27" data-id="27"> <h3 class="subsectionHead">
<span class="titlemark">26.1</span> 
<a id="x1-2800026"></a>Header and Footer for all pages</h3>
```

The following jquery code works and returns 27 as id.

```
$("#x1-2800026").closest("div").attr("id");
```

Now if the html is

```
<div class="content" id="content-27" data-id="27"> <h3 class="subsectionHead">
    <span class="titlemark">26.1</span> 
    <a id="x1-2800026.1"></a>Header and Footer for all pages</h3>
```

The following jquery code does not work...it returns undefined

```
$("#x1-2800026.1").closest("div").attr("id");
```

The only difference is of decimal place. Th id in first case is #x1-2800026 and in second case is #x1-2800026.1 
This extra decimal place seems to cause the problem. How can this be dealt with?

Comment: `.1` ... `.` is the confusion because of `classes` in query selectors being preceded by `.`

Comment: So how to deal with this? The id-s are dynamically generated. So it won't be possible to change id's.

Comment: or use `$('[id="x1-2800026.1"]')` as the selector

Comment: your code doesn't show any "dynamically generated" anything anyway

Answer (score 1):

As the selector is an id, we can fairly assume that attribute selector will give us the collection with only one element. If not, you need to correct the `html`.

```js
console.log($("[id='x1-2800026.1']").closest("div").attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" id="content-27" data-id="27"> <h3 class="subsectionHead">
    <span class="titlemark">26.1</span> 
    <a id="x1-2800026.1"></a>Header and Footer for all pages</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: if the id is dynamically generated (as per comment in the question), it follows the code could be as well, or that the selector is a variable ... I would suggest `$('[id="x1-2800026.1"]')` is more flexible - no need to deal with \ which can bite you :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - Very true.  Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @Satpal - If the value is going to be coming from a variable you will need to manipulate it, however, with the above you can use it as it is

Comment: @Downvoter - What is the reason behind your downvote? Please help me with the reasoning. Thanks!

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, `$('[id="x1-2800026.1"]')` can return multiple elements as its arr tribute value selector where as ID selector will always return a single element. And  even if its a variable jQuery provide API (3.0) to escape meta characters https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/ or it can be done via "" yourVar.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&") ""

Comment: @Satpal - That's true, however, if the html has 2 elements with same id, then it is a code bug because the id selector will not guarantee the operation is being performed on the right element

Comment: @Satpal - comment in question says something about dynamic code - I think this is easier

Comment: @Satpal - ok then what if the operation was desired for the second element with the same id

Comment: @Satpal - If id's must be unique as per all of us then the above code does no harm i guess rather it avoids the manipulation required.

Comment: all good, was looking at the wrong code - you have a good point regarding uniqueness of ID - except, well, ID's must be unique, so lets assume valid HTML :p

Comment: @satpal - I have added some information. Hope it clarifies the code

Answer (score 0):

the escaping rules from the [jQuery selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as follows

```
$("#x1-2800026\\.1").closest("div").attr("id");
```